# Data type for huge binary numbers

Tags: binary

I have to handle huge binary numbers (<=4096 digits) - what is the best way to handle such big numbers? I have to multiply them afterward and apply the %-operation on these numbers.
Do I have to use structs or how am I supposed to handle such data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got it as a string of 4096 digit, you can convert it into a list with separate smaller chunks (eg into bytes each consisting of 8 bits), then if you need to multiply/apply the %-operation on these numbers, you probably will need create a function that converts those "chunks" from binary to denary (so you can multiply them and so on.)